# How to create radio group in swift3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

How to implement radio group functionality in swift3.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no such UI element as radio button in iOS, although you could try various third party implementations out there.

Comment: [GDCheckbox](https://github.com/SaeidBsn/GDCheckbox)

Comment: or [LTHRadioButton](https://github.com/rolandleth/LTHRadioButton)

Comment: check box is multiple selction and radio is single selction, but your question is not clear

Answer (score 2):

In iOS, the standard control which serves the function of a radio control is [UISegmentedControl](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol).

```
let segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(items: ["Option A", "Option B", "Option C"])

// Don't forget to have the @IBAction valueChanged(_:)
segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(valueChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

// Set the constraints or frame

view.addSubview(segmentedControl)
```

Comment: +1. You can also use a table view like a screenshot in [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-views/tables/)

Comment: @hoseokchoi That table view layout does look really nice

Answer (score 0):

There is no radio group feature in ios.

**How you do it?**

Create a button and make two versions of image of it.
one for selected and one for deselected.

And you have to manually handle logic for group of radio buttons.

Me also waiting for this feature. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating an iOS application and don't want it to look like a Windows mutant, you should rethink the UI design to leverage and abide by the UI controls that are familiar to iOS users (as suggested in other responses).

If, however you're looking for a way to implement mutual exclusion, there are several approaches you could use but, AFAIK, none of them are "out of the box". They will all require a bit of coding.

One approach could be to place buttons in an outlet collection (in interface builder),  link them all to the same IBAction and use the outlet collection to "uncheck" all but the one that sent the event (sender).

For example:

```
@IBOutlet var exclusiveItems:[UIButton]
@IBAction func exclusiveItemSelected(_ sender: Any) 
{
  exclusiveItems.forEach{$0.selected = $0 === sender }
}
```

Instead of the .selected attribute, you could change the image or use an emoji and change the label. e.g. ✅ <=> ❎

If you're going to be using this in several places, I would suggest creating a subclass of the UI control to keep the behaviour consistant and avoid boiler plate code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use UI button instead of this take one UIButton
set a two states one is default and one is selected (*can done via storyboard* )

```
  if state == selected then value is true
    if state == default then value is false
```